# AJAX call I receive the “/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)” error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I know that there are many similar questions here and feel that I really have tried all the others, replacing the answers code into mine, testing and retesting... still no further and have been doing this for so many hours... [trying to pass a js var, into wordpress]

...really appreciate any help anyone can give.

In the console, I get a 400 error...

```
//functions file:
//getting vars from ajax
function our_tutorial(){
    $testing = 'not set';

    if(isset($_REQUEST)){
        $testing = $_REQUEST['php_test'];

    }//end is set
    return $testing;
}//end function
add_action('wp_ajax_php_tutorial', 'our_tutorial'); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_php_tutorial', 'our_tutorial' ); // for non logged in users
```

js file: [extracted from a function, rest of the function working as it should be, tested and retested]

```
///....

var test = '667'
var jaxscript = 'https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; //absolute ref for testing

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxscript,
    data: {
        'action': 'php_tutorial',
        'php_test': test
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Happy");
    }
});

///....rest of function and closing function '}'
```

Comment: There's a typo on your code. You're declaring `var jaxscript` and then on your AJAX call you're using `ajaxscript`. Notice the difference?

Comment: Also, missing semicolon after `var test = '667'`.

Comment: thank you so much ->I really have been looking at this too long... you have helped a lot :) ... I am no longer getting the 400 error... which is fantastic... the console is logging the 'Happy' part but the $_REQUEST is not being received... any further thoughts [and again, a BIG THANK YOU]

Answer (score 3):

First, change

> var jaxscript

to

> var ajaxscript

```
var test = '667'
var ajaxscript = 'http://testing.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; //absolute ref for testing

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxscript,
    data: {
        'action': 'php_tutorial',
        'php_test': test
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
   }
});
```

And use echo in place of return and use **wp_die();** before closing function

```
function our_tutorial(){
    $testing = 'not set';

    if(isset($_REQUEST)){
        $testing = $_REQUEST['php_test'];
    }

    echo json_encode($testing);
    wp_die();

}
 add_action('wp_ajax_php_tutorial', 'our_tutorial'); 
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_php_tutorial', 'our_tutorial' );
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to reply, you have been a great help too... I AM REALLY GREATFULL. I might be approaching this wrong, but am hoping that I can return the result from the function, and set it to a var elsewhere  [as I am trying to retrieve the users selection and place parts of it on an email that is being created]... is it not possible to return the result......sorry if this is a silly question.... very new to ajax with wp....  ....again, thanks for taking the time, really appreciate you having a look, in the first place as I am close to insanity :)

Comment: Hello!,
No, you can't return value when you are using Ajax to call any function.
Thank you